# how to stop decrement to minus in setState

Tags: reactjs

counter is a component in which i placed a decrement button in its I want that if the value is zero it will stop going to negative values  I have set `this.setState({counters : counters === 0 ? counters : 0 })` but it is not working its giving error
[image]

here is my code

```
class Counters extends Component {
    state={
        counters:[
            {id:1, value:0},
            {id:2, value:0},
            {id:3, value:0},
            {id:4, value:0}
        ],
       

    }
    handleIncrement=counter=>{
        const counters =[...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index]={...counter}
        counters[index].value++;
        this.setState({counters})
    }
    handleDecrement=counter=>{
        const counters =[...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index]={...counter}
        counters[index].value--;

        this.setState({counters : counters === 0 ? counters : 0 })
    }
    handleDelete=(counterid)=>{
      const counters = this.state.counters.filter(m=>m.id !== counterid)
      this.setState({counters})
    }
    handleReset=()=>{
        const counters = this.state.counters.map(m=>{ 
            m.value = 0;
             return m
        })
        this.setState({counters})

    }
    
    render() {
        
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.counters.reduce((a,b)=>({value:a.value+b.value})).value}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.handleReset} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">RESET</button>
           {this.state.counters.map(m=>
           <Counter key={m.id} 
             id={m.id} getDelete={this.handleDelete}
              onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
              onDecrement={this.handleDecrement}
              counter={m}
              >
           
              
           </Counter>) }


            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

this is the result
[image]

Comment: `counters` is an array, why are you comparing it to `0`? That will always be false, which calls `this.setState({ counters: 0 })` and `0` is a number, which does not have a `reduce()` method.

Comment: i want to stop for going negative decrement

Comment: Did you meant this.setState({counters : counters.length === 0 ? [] : counters })

Comment: @MBB no, I don't think they did... that doesn't make any sense either

Comment: i mean when i click on decrement button after zero it goes to negative -1 -2 -3  i want to stop at zero

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
counters[index].value--;
this.setState({counters : counters === 0 ? counters : 0 });
```

to

```
counters[index].value = Math.max(counters[index].value - 1, 0);
this.setState({ counters });
```

Answer (score 1):

your issue is that the `setState()` is not synchronous.

the solution is to use the callback syntax instead of the object syntax

```
handleDecrement = counter => {
    this.setState(oldstate => ({
        counters: oldstate.counters.map(item => {
            if (item.id != counter.id) return item;
            return {
                id: item.id, 
                value: (item.value > 0) ? (item.value -1) : 0
            };
        })
    }))
}
```

https://en.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: why we pass oldstate parameter can you explain it

Comment: this.setState( {counters:( oldState.counters > 0) ? (oldState.counters - 1) : 0 } )
why dont use it like this

Comment: setState is asynchronous. so between the time you read the value of a state variable, here `counters` and the time that the value is updated, that variable can change value. so if you have `counters = 3` and you decrement three times really fast, then setState would set `counters = 2` three times, and your final value would be `2` not `0`. Using the function syntax setState will use the latest value, so set to `counters=2` then `counters=1` then `counters=0`

Comment: oldstate is not a function  why u pass as parameter

Comment: `oldState => ()` is the arrow syntax of a function, you can write it `function (oldState) {}` if you prefer but either way it is a function

Comment: handleDecrement=counter=>{
        const counters =[...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index]={...counter}
        counters[index].value--;
        this.setState(oldState => (
            {counters:( oldState.counters > 0) ? (oldState.counters - 1) : 0 }
        ))
       
    }